# Disprove that for all primes $p$ if $a_{p-2}a_{p-3}...a_{2}a_{1}a_{0}$ is a multiple of $p$ then...

Tags: proof-writing, prime-numbers

Disprove that for all primes $p$ if $a_{p-2}a_{p-3}...a_{2}a_{1}a_{0}$ is a multiple of $p$ then $a_{p-3}a_{p-4}...a_{2}a_{1}a_{0}a_{p-2}$ is also a multiple of $p$.

Assume all digits are non-zero such that $1\le{a_{i}}\le9$ for each $i$.

Need some help, thanks!

Comment: **Hint** $ $  Call them $a$ and $b$. If $\,p\mid a\,$ then $\, b = 10a + a_{\large p-2}(\color{#c00}{1-10^{\large\, p-1}})\equiv 10a\equiv 0\pmod{\!p}\,$ if $\,p\nmid 10\,$ by $\rm\color{#c00}{Fermat}$. So examine $\,p=5\ \ $

Comment: I'm still not sure how to disprove from there

Comment: We want $\, 5\mid  abcd\, $ but $\,5\nmid bcda,\,$ with all digits nonzero. Recall that integers in decimal rep are multiples of $5$ iff their units digit is. So we need $\,5\mid d,\ 5\nmid a\ \ $

Comment: Basically, for $p=5$  the divisibility test tells you that (in base $10$) a number is divisible by $5$ if and only if its first digit is either $5$ or $0$. Now, you have to use this fact to see that if $a_{p-2}$ above is not $5$ then that number ending with $a_{p-2}$ won't be a multiple of $5$. Similarly, if you design $a_0$ to be $5$ then any number ending with $a_0$ will be a multiple of $5$. Therefore, you can find plenty of disproving counterexamples to your  statement : for example, $5$ divides $3125$ but not $1253$.

Comment: So the $a$ are the digits, not multiplicands?